# how to ignore relatively small values in matrices calculations in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical

Let's say we have a matrix A=[1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0.00001 0.000002 0.00003] in Matlab.
Do you know how to ignore (consider as 0) the small values in it when calculating the rank for example? what i need is a general solution to such problems!

Comment: What is your definitions of small? Would [round](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) the numbers do?

Comment: I meant that i can put somehow a threshold to define the small values, or even better if i can put a relative threshold based on the values of the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... pick a threshold and set anything below that to 0?

```
threshold = 0.0001;
A(A < threshold) = 0
```

Or else depending on the rest of `A` you could just round off:

```
floor(A) %// or round(A) or fix(A)...
```

Comment: Great thanks! but do u know a way to sent the threshold in the whole environment? not only for one object!

Comment: @Ziad that sounds like a very bad idea... why would you want to do that?

Comment: What you wrote is enough for now, because i want to calculate the rank of a real world matrix, i know that the values in the matrix will never reach zero in time, but they will be relatively small. I don't really need the "environmental threshold" for now.

Comment: Why i can't accept an answer before 10 minutes? there are wired constraints in this site!!

Comment: In case a better answer come up, this way more interest is generated in the question I guess

Comment: @Ziad You should wait a day or to before accepting. Many don't bother to look at accepted answers. This ensures that the question gets enough attention, i.e. more votes on the question and the answers.

Comment: @Ziad another thing you might consider is to explicitly cast your variable `A` to be of an integer type. This way any calculations you perform automatically return integers e.g. `A = uint8([1,2,3]);` now an operation like `A/3` will return `[0,0,1]`...

Comment: @kkuilla i guess you are right, I'm still new here, a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Thresholding, which has already been listed here, is a simple solution which will work in some cases and will break in other cases. It might be fine for you.

For the *specific* problem of finding the rank of a matrix, the more correct answer is to use the singular value decomposition. In your example, it would look something like this:

```
threshold = 0.001;
s = svd(A)
effectiveRank = sum(s/s(1) > threshold);
```

The entries of `s` are sorted from largest to smallest. Dividing by s(1) gives you immunity to scaling A.